# Xampp como solução corporativa para um servidor web com aplicações php

Tags: php, aplicação-web, servidor, xampp

Tenho uma maquina que servirá como um servidor web, com aplicações em php e aplicações com servidor embutido como pentaho e odoo erp, que serão utilizados como sistemas intranet e extranet.

Referente ao xampp, alguém com experiência me indicaria como solução corporativa para aplicações php que sofrerá grandes requisições internas e externas?

A principio era pra ser utilizado o Debian como servidor web, porém, estamos com o windows 7 instalado.

Comment: Windows 7 é um sistema Desktop, utilizá-lo como servidor de produção é um tiro no pé. 

Xampp é configurado para fins de desenvolvimento, não produção. 

Recomendo que pesquise sobre melhores praticas de como implantar corretamente um servidor PHP ao invés de ir atrás do fácil. Se quer correr esses riscos, boa sorte.

Answer (score 5):

O Xampp é um facilitador que instala o php, apache e mysql, deixando você livre para efetuar qualquer configuração extra. Isso é bom para facilitar a montagem de um ambiente de desenvolvimento, mas não é uma opção bem vista para servidores de produção.

O fato de você ser livre para configurar tudo da forma que precisar, além de ter uma interface para administrar seus serviços reforça o argumento que a resistência ao uso deste tipo de facilitador é o purismo de alguns desenvolvedores.

Vale reforçar que a instalação destas ferramentas em sistemas baseadas em unix se dá por gerenciadores de pacotes e não feita de forma "manual". Logo não existe um argumento que prove que instalar tudo de forma manual é melhor que usando estes facilitadores.

Algo ruim em usar esse tipo de recurso é o fato de servidores descentes não contarem com interface gráfica ou serem linux, ficando você preso a um facilitador desses.

Já utilizei um facilitador desses e posso te dizer que, se os serviços forem devidamente configurados, ele lhe atenderá bem.

Agora se eu puder lhe dar uma dica, sugiro que não use sistemas operacionais de desktop em servidores. Sugiro que use um fedora ou outra distro linux, já que a instalação do apache, php e mysql é bem mais simples que no windows.

**EDIT**

*Apenas para enriquecer:* Qualquer pesquisa na internet sobre esse assunto retorna posts em blogs ou em fóruns onde o autor diz existirem problemas com incompatibilidades e mensagens de erros estranhas. Entretanto os posts são totalmente levianos e carecem de mais detalhes, levando-me a reforçar mais ainda que a resistência é purismo e as reclamações amadorismo.

Erros e mensagens estranhas ocorrem devido a má configuração, não é culpa do facilitador. O mesmo digo em relação a compatibilidade.

Claro que este edit é apenas meu ponto de vista.

Comment: Vou usar um facilitador de ambiente de desenvolvimento em um servidor de produção e vou reconfigurar depois, mas eu como um leigo sei configurar? Posso baixar individualmente e implantar com as configurações sugeridas para produção do próprio software (vide o instalador do MySQL e config do PHP). Além disso os pacotes instalam mais do que você precisa (a exemplo do Xampp que ver com um mail server). Se queremos facilidades podemos usar um pacote **para** servidores de produção (Zend Server).

Comment: @gmsantos Leigos vão fazer besteira de qualquer forma. Com um facilitador eu posso selecionar o que quero ou não instalar. Não adianta cara, isso é tudo purismo.

Comment: Não vejo como purismo, vejo como saber o que está fazendo. Mas usar um pacote com foco para o dev em produção e reconfigurar é perda de tempo, tanto que recomendei o uso do Zend Server (feito para isso) e mais recentemente temos também um production-ready para o EasyPHP como pacotes para o devido fim.

Comment: @gmsantos Concordamos em discordar.

Comment: @gmsantos uma coisa que eu gostaria que você entendesse é que muitas pessoas falam em "Pacotes para produção" de forma leviana, ngm deixa isso claro. Não sou especialista em PHP como você e para mim instalar o Apache com os módulos que meu app necessita e configura-lo para questões específicas de segurança, acesso e gerenciamento de recursos (escolhendo o *ini* mais adequado) é o suficiente  e deve ser feito de qualquer forma, independente do que é usado. Me mostre claramente que estou errado com alg significativo. Me mostre o poder de seu certificado PHP :D. Deixe o site mais rico.

Comment: Além do Apache é importante configurar diretivas do PHP como exibição de erros, armazenamento de logs, consumo de memória do PHP e também do MySQL (no servidor deve ser maior que na maquina de desenvolvimento). Ambos ambientes tem necessidades diferentes e uma configuração mais braçal garante que certos gargalos sejam eliminados na raiz. Caso tenha alguma dúvida específica, por favor poste no formato de pergunta.

Comment: @gmsantos Tudo isso pode ser feito usando o xammp, wamp, EasyPhp e outros facilitadores, bastando configurar o php.ini, mysql.ini e httpd.conf. Como eu já falei: Esses facilitadores apenas instalam as ferramentas mas a configuração é livre, se isso da mais ou menos trabalho não está no escopo da pergunta, já que isso é pessoal. Não posso deixar de concordar com a sua colocação, afinal você tem know how, agora também não posso dizer que é pior usar um facilitador porque não existem evidencias claras de sua ineficácia. O que eu pedi pra você foi uma evidência clara no formato de benchmark.

Comment: Agradeço a todos que comentaram, ajudou muito na tomada de decisão.